# Scaling Large Concurrent API Requests For Large Data Sets

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, rabbitmq, activemq-classic

I am designing a component (component A) of a notification application that is integrating with a REST API (component B) which can accept a max of 10,000 concurrent requests. The data being sent is less than 1KB and will be stored in a NoSQL DB which will be read by component A and then sent to component B as concurrent as possible.  I would like to concurrently send 10,000 requests from component A to component B.  I'm planning on putting either rabbitmq or activemq between component A and B in order to control the thread counts and scale the concurrent processing in order to send a large number of concurrent requests (10,000).

**Component A:**

```
    -read all documents (less than 1kb each) from NoSQL database 
    -create JMS message and push data to rabbitmq or activemq
    -the 10,000 rabbitmq or activemq listener/consumer threads will concurrently consume, 
     transform NoSQL object graph to the request needed by component B and call component B 
     and repeat until all messages are sent to component B
```

**Component B:**

```
-can't handle more than 10,000 concurrent requests
-wont support a bulk API
```

The data set can get into the millions and a million messages will need to be processed and sent from component A to component B as fast as possible. I'm looking into batching the messages together.

Any design ideas regarding scaling this would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it sounds like you're on the right path already

RabbitMQ can handle 100,000+ messages per minute, so it shouldn't have any issue hitting your 10K concurrent requests with Component B

As a message consumer, you can use a [consumer prefetch](https://www.rabbitmq.com/consumer-prefetch.html) setting to tell RabbitMQ how many messages it can handle at one time.

Set the prefetch to 10,000 (or less) for the code that reads from RabbitMQ, transforms the object graph and and posts to your REST api. With that in place, you should be good to go.

Comment: thanks Derick Bailey, any experiences of your own where RabbitMQ outperformed ActiveMQ for my use case?

Comment: I don't have any real experience with activemq, so i can't really speak to how it works / performs. but i would expect either RMQ or AMQ to be a good choice.